# LSI for Gaussian measure in $({\mathbb{R}^d})^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

I am looking for a reference: Does Gaussian measure satisfy Logarithmic Sobolev Inequality (LSI) in $\({\mathbb{R}^d}\)^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what space you're looking at?  Do you mean the space of functions $\mathbb{Z}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$, or equivalently a countably infinite product of copies of $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: If so, and you mean standard Gaussian measure, then this is the same as asking about standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, which should be dealt with in most standard references on LSIs. 

Comment: It is the case of standard Gaussian measure on product of countably infinite copies of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Could you please mention any references on this? All I could find is, LSI for standard GM on $\mathbb{R}^d$ but not the product space.

Answer (score 2):

As in Mark Meckes's comment, this is equivalent to log-Sobolev for standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, which in turn follows immediately from the finite-dimensional case.  In order to show the log-Sobolev inequality
$$\int |f|^2 \ln |f|  \le \int \|\nabla f\| + \frac{1}{2} \int |f|^2 \ln \int |f|^2$$
it is sufficient to prove it for smooth cylinder functions $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}, \mu)$, i.e. which depend on only finitely many coordinates.  But for $f$ depending on $n$ coordinates, this is precisely the log-Sobolev inequality for standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  (Unlike the classical Sobolev inequality, there is no dimension-dependent constant!)

Leonard Gross's original paper introducing the log-Sobolev inequality already mentions the extension to infinite dimensions (though it does not work it out explicitly).

> Gross, Leonard.  Logarithmic Sobolev Inequalities. *American Journal of Mathematics* **97** No. 4 (Winter, 1975), pp. 1061-1083.

Comment: Thanks, Nate.  I got busy and didn't get back to this in time.